# Is there an efficient way to create a table its columns number and names are based on a dynamic html form

Tags: php, jquery, phpmyadmin

I am working on creating a web-based grade sheet using mysql and php. An admin create column dynamically using jquery item names can be entered such as project1, mid-term etc. I want to create a table based on the admin selection. Example, if admin adds three items(assignment1, assignment2, final exam), a table gets created with column (assignment1, assignment2, final exam).

Comment: I'm not sure, but there probably is a way..

Comment: If you already use JQuery, take a look at datatable.js It has a lot of cool feature to manupulate tables dynamically https://datatables.net/

Comment: Your question doesn't actually ask a question. Its a description of what you're trying to do with some code showing how you're going about it. Its not clear what you're asking. Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question so that we can help you better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write a PHP application that receives the submitted form and based on the selection, generates a CREATE TABLE statement and sends it to the MySQL server. You have examples of this statement here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html